# How to get back to main activity and make it static(main menu)after splash

Tags: android, eclipse, splash-screen

i'm very new to eclipse and programming in general. Can anyone please tell how to get back to the main activity page(main menu) after a splash screen? currently it just opens>splash screen>"stoped working"

```
package org.iimed.www;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageButton imageButton;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void AddListenerOnButton() {

        imageButton= (ImageButton) findViewById (R.id.splash);

        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View argO) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "Welcome!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show();
            }

        });
    }

            });
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to open your MainActivity after the splashscreen has bean shown if you have an animation do it when its finish. You can also do what I find the best solution to create a splash dialog and show and dismiss that instead of a splash activity.

You also don't call the AddListenerOnButton method anywhere!